# startupwmclass is not being reconized in ubuntu 21.04 with firefox

Tags: firefox, dock

I have created a desktop entry to open a specific firefox profile with it's own startupwmclass so it would show up separately in the dock but recently it is now grouped with the default profile firefox. I have the same entry on another computer running ubuntu 21.04 and it continues to show the separate icon for each firefox profile.

This is the `.desktop` file contents that resides in the `~/.local/share/applications` directory:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Firefox Gmail
Exec=firefox -P Gmail -no-remote --class GmailProfile
Icon=evolution
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=GmailProfile
```

Comment: Provide detail on what you attempted, e.g. show the desktop file. Nobody can even guess what may be wrong here based on only the info you provide.

Comment: I changed from wayland to x11 and that solved it.

Comment: Unfortunately yet something else broken by Wayland. It will be good to post your solution as a small answer to help future readers. You can also accept that answer: this is perfectly fine on this site.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by changing the windowing server from Wayland to x11(Xorg).